# Using LINQ to select with object

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, bulletedlist

I have a `Radio Bullet List`, i want to set the values and text of this radio list using LINQ, but return "0" when the first value on database is "1".

at the database i have two columns, `codcategoria` and `dsccategoria`, i want define value of `radio_bullet_list` with `codcategoria` and the display text with `dsccategoria`

```
testesiteEntities db = new testesiteEntities();//create object

//select object
rblCategoria.DataValueField = db.categoria.Select( c => c.codcategoria ).ToString(); 
rblCategoria.DataTextField = db.categoria.Select(dc => dc.dsccategoria).ToString();
rblCategoria.DataBind();//define valores no bullet list
```

what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DataValueField and DataTextField are both just looking for string representation of what they're supposed to use. You would set your DataSource to some sort of IEnumerable that actually has those properties, so assuming db.categoria has the properties "codcategoria" and "dsccategoria" you could do something like:

```
testesiteEntities db = new testesiteEntities();//create object

//select object
rblCategoria.DataValueField = "codcategoria"; 
rblCategoria.DataTextField = "dsccategoria";
rblCategoria.DataSource = db.categoria.Select().ToList();
rblCategoria.DataBind();//define valores no bullet list
```

Comment: wooow thanks, but with .Select() do error, .tolist() was enough to function.

> rblCategoria.DataSource = db.categoria.ToList();